# Not catching when ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is thrown?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program where an ArrayList is created (list), and that list is populated with 100 random integers. The user inputs an index of the array and then the program displays the corresponding ArrayList value. If the user inputs an index value that is out of bounds, then their error will be caught and a message will be displayed to them. I have set up everything needed, but each time I input an index that is out of bounds, the error is not caught and Java displays its own error message. This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayIndexOutOfBounds
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      int number;
      for (int i= 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
         number = (int)(Math.random()*21);
         list.add(number);
      }

      run(list);
   }

   public static void run(ArrayList<Integer> list)
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter an index number for the array: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       try{
      int number = input.nextInt();
      int result = list.get(number);
      System.out.println(result);
      }
      catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
      {
         System.out.println("Out of Bounds");
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: So what exception does Java actually throw?

Comment: Let's say I entered 200, it'll display this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 200, Size: 100

Comment: You're not using an array. The exception is documented in the javadoc -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int).

Comment: Catch IndexOutOfBoundsException, not ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayLists throw IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. Try replacing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex` with `IndexOutOfBoundsException ex`

Answer (score 0):

Just change exception class `IndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

More detail on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the catch block.

Use this

```
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
```

instead of this

```
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
```